# A function to check for overlapping circular elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I wrote this function to check for two overlapping elements
(which are rectangular),
As shown in the first pic below.

The problem is, i want to use circular elelemts, 
As shown in the second pic below.

So i guess i need to add some Math.PI and radiuses calculations,
Would appreciate any help...

```
       var checkOverlap = function (a, b) {
            if (
                ((a.left < b.left && a.left + a.width > b.left) ||
                (a.left > b.left && a.left + a.width < b.left + b.width) ||
                (a.left > b.left && a.left + a.width > b.left + b.width)) &&
                ((a.top < b.top && a.top + a.height > b.top) ||
                (a.top > b.top && a.top + a.height > b.top) ||
                (a.top > b.top && a.top < b.top + b.height)) &&
                (a.left < b.left + b.width) &&
                (a.top < b.top + b.height)
            ) {
                return true;
            }
        };
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two discs intersect if and only if the distance between their centres is no more than the sum of their radii.

If the coordinates of two points on a plane are `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, the distance between them is a square root of `(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2`.

You should be able to pick it up from here.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if circles overlap is easier than doing similar check with rectangles.

Assuming that you are not dealing with ellipses, you just need to calculate if distance between their centers ([Pythagoras theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)) is less than sum of their radii:

```
// long argument names to be more descriptive

function checkIfCirclesOverlap(circle1CenterX, circle1CenterY, circle1Radius, circle2CenterX, circle2CenterY, circle2Radius) {
    const xDistance = circle1CenterX - circle2CenterX;
    const yDistance = circle1CenterY - circle2CenterY;
    const distance = Math.sqrt(xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance);
    return distance < circle1Radius + circle2Radius;
}
```

Comment: it probably should be less *or equal*. If the distance equals to the sum of radii, there's still one point of intersection.

Comment: Yup, actually it depends on the requirements - i don't know if something should happen on touching or rather overlapping.